# How can I get rid of the animation when resetting my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, reset

I want to have a menu button that allows the user to reset the app. As I've read that I shouldn't call onCreate() manually, I use the following code instead:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

My problem is that this triggers an animation where the window disappears and appears again, which I don't want to happen. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what animation you mean and what resetting your app means but if you're talking about the transition animation you can remove it by calling:

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

before your start activity or before you call `setContentView`

Make sure you override your `onFinish` method if you're going to call that method on the second activity and add it there too:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
}
```

**EDIT**

Is this what you want?

```
final Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}, 500);
```

Comment: By resetting my app I mean getting rid of its state, that is to say, I want to achieve the same effect as if the app had been closed and then started again. There is only one activity, which I am finishing and then starting again to achieve this "resetting" effect.

Comment: Check my edit. Just wait a bit before you start your activity and it will look like you closed your app.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain myself well. The point is: My app has a lot of things, like counters, the content of textEdits,etc. I want the user to be able to restart all of those, as if he was starting the app from scratch. Instead of restarting all the elements one by one, I think it is better to just restart the whole activity. The problem is that an animation appears, and  I DO NOT want to see a transition animation.What I try to do is to eliminate that animation keeping my original code.

Comment: That's what I told you earlier. Use ` overridePendingTransition`